# Make an mp3 file play continuously

Tags: java, audio

So, I'm making a game for my Computer Science class and I recently ran into a problem: The music that plays on the title screen stops when the mp3 file is finished playing. I have an MP3 class and a Music class but I can't figure out how to make the MP3 play again once the song is done. Here is my MP3 class:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
public class MP3 
{
    String filename;
    Player player; 

    public void stopMP3() { if (player != null) player.close(); }

    // play the MP3 file to the sound card
    public void playMP3(String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            player = new Player(bis);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // run in new thread to play in background
        new Thread() 
        {
            public void run() {
                try {player.play(); }
                catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e); }
            }
        }.start();
    }  
}
```

and here is my Music class:

```
import java.io.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Music
{
    private ArrayList<String> songs;

    public Music(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        songs = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            songs.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    public String getRandSong()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randSongIndex = r.nextInt(songs.size());
        return songs.get(randSongIndex);
    }
}
```

I was thinking of making a method in my music class but I don't know how to check if the MP3 is finished or not. By the way, I have only been programming in Java for a little under a year, so if you have any other suggestions for my code, I'll gladly take them. Also, the entire program is intended to run on a computer, not any handheld devices, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

How about using mp3agic library to get attributes of the mp3 file.

This library has one class called Mp3File and inside the class a method is defined to get the length of the file in seconds.

```
Mp3File file = new Mp3File(songAbsolutePath);
long mp3LengthInSeconds = file.getLengthInSeconds();
```

Once you got the length in seconds then you can decide if the song is completed or not.

Once the play is started, another thread can sleep for specified seconds and then again invoke the mP3 file.

This library also has so many other functions which read ID3v1, ID3v2 and other tags of mp3 file and gives you proper output.

Comment: Thanks! This works, except I don't know what you mean by making another thread sleep for specified seconds. I'm not familiar with that. Do you mind letting me know what it means?

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you.
By other thread, I meant thread which will invoke the "playMP3" function of   MP3 class and then it will sleep till the mp3 continues to play. The playback and the sleep will have the equal duration. so once the playback is done, the thread will select the next random song, play and again sleep.

something like this, (main function in your MP3 class)

Comment: something like this, (main function in your MP3 class)

take a look at this code, which uses your MP3 and Music class

[http://ideone.com/UEhSbG](http://ideone.com/UEhSbG)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the mp3 file over and over again, you can put the `while` loop:

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    player.play();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e); }
        }
    }.start();
```

When the previous [`Player#play`](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/Player.html#play%28%29) method ends, then the `while` loop will repeat and a second call to `Player#play` will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar solution to @Willem. But adding more details. If you let your player play in an infinite loop, you need to stop it some time. So, check a static boolean variable to stop playing. This is just a start. You can add more controls.

```
package audio;

public class InfiniteLoop {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws InterruptedException {
        // run in new thread to play in background
        Play p1 = new Play(1);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        t1.start();
        // Let it play for 10 seconds. Then stop.
        System.out.println("Thread is playing in background");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        // Stop it.
        p1.setStop(true);
    }
}

class Play implements Runnable {
    boolean stopped = false;
    int id;

    Play(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setStop(boolean b) {
        this.stopped = b;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!stopped) {
                // This is a sample code. Add your player code here.
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(id + " " + "playing");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AdvancedPlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/AdvancedPlayer.html) instead of Player.  Then you can set a listener which will be notified when playback finishes:

```
AdvancedPlayer player;

// ...

player = new AdvancedPlayer(bis);
player.setPlayBackListener(new PlaybackListener() {
    @Override
    public void playbackStarted(PlaybackEvent event) { }

    @Override
    public void playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent event) {
        playMP3(filename);
    }
});
```