# How I can check when music has ended

Tags: java, swing, audio

I have a JFrame with 2 buttons: Turn On and Turn Off

My problem is when a song has ended, I can't check that it ended and to play it again

How can I check it? Thank you so much
Below is the way that I play sound on Swing

```
class MP3 {
private Player player;
private String filename;

public MP3(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}
public void stop() {
    if (player != null)
        player.close();
}
public void play() {

    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        player = new Player(bis);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                player.play();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

And Event when I click buttons

```
private void btnPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    sound = new MP3("src/Sound/02 - Cold Pizza.mp3");
    sound.play();
    btnPlay.setVisible(false);
    btnStop.setVisible(true);
}                                       

private void btnStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    sound.stop();
    btnStop.setVisible(false);
    btnPlay.setVisible(true);
}
```

`sound` is a instance of MP3 class in main class

Comment: What's the qualified name of `Player` class?

Comment: Does your `Player` class supports its own listeners?

Comment: main class's name is playmusicFrame

Comment: I use `import javazoom.jl.player.Player` and `import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException` to play music

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37974746/2055998

Comment: http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/Player.html#isComplete() But it is usually better to have the line tell you when it is finished than to keep checking the line. PM 77-1's link above shows that the class AdvancedPlayer supports a "PlaybackListener" which is probably very similar to a Java LineListener. Do you know how to use Listeners?

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1, your link help me alot

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way. I made the mp3 file a wav file. Then I made two objects

```java
AudioInputStream songReader;
Clip song;
try{
   songReader =
              AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
              getClass().getResource("wally.wav"));
   song = AudioSystem.getClip();
   song.open(songReader);
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("won't work");
}
try{
   song.stop();
   song.setFramePosition(0);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error playing your music");
}
try{
   song.start();
   song.loop(song.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Won't work");
}
```

This makes it play infinitely, but if you need you can stop it at any point with song.stop(). Hopefully, that will work for you.